# What is the difference between C and Posix locales on Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, internationalization, locale

I know that database locales on Postgres are responsible for proper order of national characters, proper lower/upper-casing etc.

But why there are two language-neutral locales: `posix` and `c`? Is there any difference between them or is it just one neutral locale with two different names?

**UPDATE** As Magnus Hagander states in his answer, POSIX and C locales are the same locale with different names (no matter if Postgres is installed on POSIX or Windows System). I don't know how to confirm this information - **where to look for proper section of documentation?**

Magnus's explanation seems sensible, but it is strange at the same time that there are two names for the same locale to choose from. **What is the purpose of this - only to make confusion?**

Answer (score 9):

Note that PostgreSQL just uses the operating system locale, and doesn't have it's own definition of locales. If your system is POSIX compliant, C and POSIX will be the exact same locale: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html (see the first sentence under 7.2).

Comment: OK, if Postgres is installed on POSIX compliant system than POSIX locale is the same as C locale. But what with non-compliant systems? Is Windows Vista POSIX-compliant? I've Vista box with Postgres and I'm always not sure what to choose POSIX or C - as this two options are both possible (among many other national-specific locales). Where should I find info about POSIX and C locales - what this means (differences) on Windows Vista?

Comment: The C locale should work the same way on Windows. I'm unsure if the POSIX locale even exists, but if it does I'd expect it to work the same way - it'd be stupid of them to implement a locale named POSIX and not make it POSIX compatible.

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Single UNIX ® Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/locale.html) POSIX and C locales are aliases:

> The strings "C" and "POSIX" are reserved as identifiers for the POSIX locale

So they are guaranteed to be the same on POSIX systems. I don't know how far Windows Vista or 7 are POSIX compliant, but probably similar definition can be found in Microsoft documentation.