# LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE support for utf-8 in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

From this link http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:Collate and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html. it's make me confused.

They said, `utf-8` support depends on OS capability, and its deferent between every `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` options.

When I create database using `pdAdmin III`, there is 3 option, `C, Posix and English_United States.1252`. What's the different between `C, Posix and English_United States.1252`?

I want work with all languages supported, that is `unicode utf-8`, which doesn't seem to be an option.

What I must chose for the values of `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` for creating database that support `utf-8` in `PostgreSQL 9`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As documentation, [22.2. Character Set Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) says:

> An important restriction, however, is
>   that each database's character set
>   must be compatible with the database's
>   LC_CTYPE (character classification)
>   and LC_COLLATE (string sort order)
>   locale settings. For C or POSIX
>   locale, any character set is allowed,
>   but for other locales there is only
>   one character set that will work
>   correctly. (On Windows, however, UTF-8
>   encoding can be used with **any locale**.)

I see that probably you have PostgreSQL under Windows host (`English_United States.1252 locale`), so you can use whatever of these (`Posix` is as same as `C` and means "no locale"), read [22.1. Locale Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html):

> Locale support refers to an
>   application respecting cultural
>   preferences regarding alphabets,
>   sorting, number formatting, etc.
>
> If you want the system to behave as if
>   it had no locale support, use the
>   special locale C or POSIX.

**EDIT:**

Windows platform isn't POSIX compliant, so you should use `C` locale for that platform. I don't know why installer has POSIX option (I guess it's rather a bug):

[image]

To create new cluster without locale you can simply use `--no-locale` switch e.g.:

```
initdb --no-locale -E UTF-8 C:\pgdata
```

Comment: But i got problem.
i try to reinstal the postgresql, then in the beginning installation, i chose POSIX. after finish, i try to create new database, but i got Error "invalid locale name POSIX"

Comment: @Ahmad: Try to use `C` instead.

Comment: C is work fine when i use template0. but what is template0 ? and i saw template1 also. what the different ? and why POSIX is not work even when i use template0 ?

i also try using Windows command > initdb --locale=POSIX -E UTF8 -D pgdata

but u got the same error 'initdb: invalid locale name "POSIX"'

Comment: i read from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html. that template0 is a virgin version, but in the first install i chose POSIX. why now i can't use POSIX and must C ?

Comment: @Ahmad: That is good question. Windows is not POSIX compliant, so I think it's normal that is `POSIX` locale is unsupported. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355051/what-is-the-difference-between-c-and-posix-locales-on-postgres

Comment: --no-locale and --locale=C are the same in Postgres. (See Documentation for initdb command on postgres site)